# unable to install glassfish support on eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, jakarta-ee, glassfish

This is the problem i face when i try to download glassfish support on eclipse. What is this ? And how can i get rid of this ?

[image]

Comment: The installer can't find the jars at the given URLs. That's all. Server down or URL has changed.

Comment: @ Andreas_D this is the problem i am facing from the last 20 hours. I am installing the glassfih support after clicking _download additional server adapter_ in eclipse

Comment: Do you get the files if you enter the URL in your browser? You may get a solution through oracles support forums.

Answer (score 1):

Read timeout when trying to reach the jars required for installation. Do other updates work within eclipse? Is network connection fine outside eclipse? If fine outside eclipse check eclipse network settings. If not fine outside eclipse check OS network settings first.

For Eclipse select from menu: "Window" > "Preferences". Then type filter text "network" or select "General" > "Network Connections". There you can define proxy if needed.

Comment: everything is fine. what do i need to check in the eclipse network settings ?